# Cannot find module 'D:\nodejs\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js'

Tags: node.js, webpack, cmd

When I run 'webpack' in cmd, it gives me an error:

`Cannot find module 'D:\nodejs\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js`

But I get correct result when I run it in Git Bash.

I have set the `NODE_PATH` and `install webpack global`

[CMD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4tCy.png)

[Git Bash Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH6sf.png)

Comment: It's looking for the module on `D:`, so maybe it's on `C:` instead?

Answer (score 12):

Try this in your CMD

```
npm remove webpack -g
npm i webpack --save-dev
npm run webpack
```

Comment: Got an error on the 3rd command, but stuff still started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Steps indicated by DragonBorn work fine, just make sure you are not in a VPN or some how restricted network, two attempts failed until i tried again disconected from a VPN